# Android Creating a stored setting

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I'm making a function in my android app that, at a home screen the user has the choice to view a league or choose a team. I want to know if its possible to and how to store their team selection so that it doesn't go to that activity the next time they start the app.
Also, how would I implement a menu button to change that team if they so wish?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) will allow you to store your league/team selection. You can retrieve this when you start your application and move to your next activity if it is set.

Look how to create Menu items in Android [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html). These are straight forward and very easy to implement. Just have that menu button launch your "select a team/league" activity

Answer (score 0):

This should be something trivial that you should have been able to google:

For persisting simple data you can use [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html)